# Swift - Mac OS - Trying to launch a Python script from a menu app results in failure

Tags: python, swift, xcode, macos

New to Swift and Mac OS development

I was following the tutorial here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/165853/menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps-macos

I want a simple menu app that will let me launch certain python scripts.

Here is the code I am using to launch the python script

```
@objc func launchPythonScript(_ sender: Any?) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/python"
    task.arguments = ["-c", "\"print 'hello world'\""]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

for some reason when I click the button to launch it doesn't error out but goes into a debug mode where I see assembly statements and the error:

`Thread 1: EXC_SOFTWARE (code=131072, subcode=0x0)`

Any ideas on how I can solve this?  I must be doing something simple wrong.

Comment: Xcode6? Xcode9 is the current version with 10beta already out, why are you using such an old version.

Comment: Oh sorry, no xcode 9.4. Selected the wrong tag @DávidPásztor

Comment: `waitUntilExit` blocks the current thread, so it isn't wise to use it in an action method of a menu item.

Comment: @mschmidt makes sense. I doubt that is causing the hang though. It’s almost like something is stopping the execution of my program.